# How to use mapKeys and group values by key in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, json, object, mapping, lodash

Initially, I'm having the object:

```
let root = {};
root["myRootNode"] = { 
   id1: {
     age: "17",
     name: "name1",
     surname: "surname1"                    
  },
   id2: {
     age: "11",
     name: "name2",
     surname: "surname2"                    
  },
   id3: {
     age: "25",
     name: "name1",
     surname: "surname3"                    
  }
};
```

And what I want to do with it, is to get it into the state:

```
"name1": [
  {
     age: "17",
     surname: "surname1"         
  },
  {
     age: "25",
     surname: "surname3"         
  }
],
"name2": [
    age: "11",
    surname: "surname2"        
]
```

For me it's important to have the list/array of all objects, which contains this same property, grouped by the value of that property.

What I tried (using lodash) is:

```
let test = _.mapKeys(root["myRootNode"], function(value, key) {
  return value["name"];
});
```

But this gives me the result:

```
"name1": {
   age: "25"
   name: "name1"
   surname: "surname3"
},
"name2": {
   age: "11"
   name: "name2"
   surname: "surname2"
}
```

So they are not grouped and only the last value is mapped under the key which is repeating. Also in the result that I got, they are not placed under an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can use groupBy and map it's values to get rid of the `name` property.

If you don't mind leaving the `name` property can simply do `_.groupBy(root.myRootNode, 'name');`

Personally it feels like you should be using arrays instead of objects

```js
const res =
_(root.myRootNode)
  .groupBy('name')
  .mapValues((arr)=>_.map(arr, (o) =>_.omit(o,['name'])))
  .value()



console.log(res)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>

<script>
let root = {};
root["myRootNode"] = { 
   id1: {
     age: "17",
     name: "name1",
     surname: "surname1"                    
  },
   id2: {
     age: "11",
     name: "name2",
     surname: "surname2"                    
  },
   id3: {
     age: "25",
     name: "name1",
     surname: "surname3"                    
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: Also seems strange you don't want the id in this mapped version

Answer (score 1):

Here's a shot at it. The idea is to create an array for each new name and push all entries onto the corresponding name array.

```js
const root = {
  myRootNode: {
    id1: {
      age: "17",
      name: "name1",
      surname: "surname1"
    },
    id2: {
      age: "11",
      name: "name2",
      surname: "surname2"
    },
    id3: {
      age: "25",
      name: "name1",
      surname: "surname3"
    }
  }
};

const result = Object.values(root.myRootNode).reduce((a, e) => {
  if (!(e.name in a)) {
    a[e.name] = [];
  }

  a[e.name].push({
    age: e.age,
    surname: e.surname
  });

  return a;
}, {});

console.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 4));
```